# How to save screenshot to android device by appium+selenium

Tags: android, selenium, automation, screenshot, appium

Does anybody know how to save screenshot taken from real android device by appium+selenium to device local storage?
Here I have method which can take screenshot from device and save it to PC storage. 
But how to set path to save them on real device folder (e.g. deviceName\tablet\GUI\screenshots\screenshot.jpg ...or other way), 
taking into account that code should run on PC.

p.s. My app is hybrid so I make switch context to "NATIVE_APP" and then back to WEBVIEW.

```
    public static void getScreenshot(String screenName) throws IOException {
    String contextName = AppiumConfigurationTest.driver.getContext();
    AppiumConfigurationTest.driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

    String Screenshotpath = "C:\\!automation\\build\\reports\\gui_screen_capture\\";
    File screenShot = AppiumConfigurationTest.driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, new File(Screenshotpath + screenName+"_ " + "." + "jpg"));

    AppiumConfigurationTest.driver.context(contextName);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute adb command from your code, in which case this shall help you :

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
```

**Note** : Saving the screenshots on laptop with different named tests/build is better than saving them on devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) appiumDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

BufferedImage originalImage=null;

try {
    originalImage= ImageIO.read(((TakesScreenshot) appiumDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\nbuffered image" + originalImage +"\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("buffered image" + originalImage);
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();
BufferedImage resizedImage = CommonUtilities.resizeImage(originalImage, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH);
            ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "jpg", new File(path + "/"+ testCaseId + "/img/" + index + ".jpg"));
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: ImageIO.write will save the image to the path